# ¿Cómo obtener un arreglo de una consulta preparada con mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, poo

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo del cual quiero sacar un array asociativo o usando otras consultas obtener el resultado de la mysqli preparada. 
quiero saber como obtener resultados.

```
     $query="SELECT username, pass FROM  administrador WHERE username= ? AND pass= ?";
     $sentencia=$mysqli->prepare($query);
     $sentenca->bind_param("s,s",$usr,$pass);
     $sentencia->execute();
```

Quiero obetener un array asociativo de esa consulta, con mysqli consulta no preparada lo obtenia con mysqli_query()

Comment: Aparte de tu pregunta tienes un pequeño fallo en tu `bind_param()` tienes un `,` demás, fíjate `"s,s"` debería ser `"ss"`.

Comment: Corregí mi respuesta, acabo de ver que después de un execute el statement no puedes recorerlo como si fuera un mysqli_result

Answer (score 1):

Tu objeto `$sentencia` es un statement de mysqli. Yo había pensado **incorrectamente** que podías obtener los resultados haciendo

```
while ($fila = $sentencia->fetch_assoc())
{
   print_r($fila);
}
```

**Pero eso no funciona**. Leyendo un poco más, acabo de darme cuenta de que en `mysqli` a diferencia de `PDO`, cuando usas `stmt->execute()` tienes que obtener los resultados haciendo un bind a variables.

Esto significa, en tu caso:

```
 $query="SELECT username, pass FROM  administrador WHERE username= ? AND pass= ?";
 $sentencia=$mysqli->prepare($query);
 $sentencia->bind_param("ss",$usr,$pass);
 $sentencia->execute();

 // esto es lo que yo no sabía!!!
 $sentencia->bind_result($username, $pass);

 while ($sentencia->fetch()) {
    echo "username $username tiene password $pass <br>";
 }

 $sentencia->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tenes el controlador Nativo de MySQL ([`mysqlnd`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqlnd.php)) una opción es usar [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

### Ejemplo:

```
$query="SELECT username, pass FROM  administrador WHERE username= ? AND pass= ?";
$sentencia=$mysqli->prepare($query);
$sentenca->bind_param("ss",$usr,$pass);
$sentencia->execute();

$resultado = $sentencia->get_result();
$registro = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
```